# Show DialogFragment even when Context changes

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have app in which message is sent and its report is received after sometime through `BroadcastReceiver`. This report is to be shown to the user through dialog for which I am using `DialogFragment` as shown below.

```
myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(firstTime)
            firstTime = false; 

        boolean anyError = false;
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                anyError = true;
                break;
        }

        sent.add(anyError);
        CustomAlertDialogFragment customAlertDialogFragment = CustomAlertDialogFragment.newInstance("Title",logMessage);
        customAlertDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"TAG");
        sent.clear();
    }
};
```

The code for `CustomDialog` is below.

```
public class CustomAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static CustomAlertDialogFragment newInstance(String title, String content) {
        CustomAlertDialogFragment customAlertDialogFragment = new CustomAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title",title);
        args.putString("content", content);
        customAlertDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        return customAlertDialogFragment;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        String content = getArguments().getString("content");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // title bar string
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null);

        builder.setMessage(content);
        AlertDialog errorDialog = builder.create();
        // return the Dialog object
        return errorDialog;
    }
}
```

If the user moves to any other `Fragment` or `Activity` meanwhile, the dialog is not shown. It should throw `NullPointerException` if its not getting context but its not. What can be the possible alternative or solution to this. I have referred other SO questions where members have asked to use notification instead but my requirement is dialog. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dialogue` is throwing an exception named `window leaked` I guess. In your case I think you may think of using the `Application` class.

Anyway, you may register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Application` class for your case, which will receive the broadcast and will show the dialog on demand.

To retrive the `Context` you may use `getApplicationContext()`.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    // Declare the BroadcastReceiver in your Application class
    BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(firstTime)
                firstTime = false; 

            boolean anyError = false;
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    anyError = true;
                    break;
            }

            sent.add(anyError);
            CustomAlertDialogFragment customAlertDialogFragment = CustomAlertDialogFragment.newInstance("Title",logMessage);
            customAlertDialogFragment.show(getApplicationContext().getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
            sent.clear();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Register the receiver here 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Un-register the receiver here 
    }
}
```

To register the `Application` class in your manifest you need to define the name

```
<application
    android:name="Yourpackage.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/your_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">

    <!-- Your activities -->
</application>
```